# Bold not working on a page but works on other pages and browsers

Tags: html

I am trying to create a small description tile on a web page and i realized that bold ( tag) isn't causing the desired effect(or any effect at all) on a particular page. This is the code that I am using, which to my knowledge is correct:

```
<div class="w48 contentBox contentBoxBlue" style="margin:1%;margin:0 auto;">
<img style="width:25%;margin-bottom:5%;" src="styles/images/piggyWhite.png" />
<p class="tWhite tCenter"><b>Pay Per Hire</b><br>Participate for free and pay per hire</p>
</div>
```

I tried looking around on stackoverflow but couldn't find any similar posts. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance people!!

EDIT: This may be caused by any overriding css property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that it may be being removed by another CSS rule, for example:

```
.twhite b { font-weight: normal; }
```

If you are using chrome, right-click on it and choose "Inspect Element", then see what CSS rules are being applied.  That will give you your answer.

Comment: Oh silly me!! Thanks a lot MrZebra.That was the issue.